# Can't return value of polygon with trp module?

Tags: python, amazon-textract

I have an amazon textract response that I am trying to extract the polygon values from.

My code is as follows:

```
doc = Document(response)
polygons= []

# Iterate over elements in the document
for page in doc.pages:
    for field in page.form.fields:
        polygons.append(field.geometry.polygon)
```

When I do this, my output is as follows:

```
  [[<trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9fb80>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9fd90>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9fe50>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9feb0>],
 [<trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9bd30>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9bfa0>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9bac0>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22671e9bb20>],
 [<trp.Polygon at 0x22672e017f0>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22672e018b0>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22672e01700>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22672e01910>],
...
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22672e02070>],
 [<trp.Polygon at 0x22672dfa1c0>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22672dfa8e0>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22672dfa9a0>,
  <trp.Polygon at 0x22672dfa7f0>]]
```

Does anyone know how to extract the actual values? I have tried using field.geometry.polygon.text, which does not work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the `textract` [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_Point.html) a **Polygon** is a list of **Points**. A Point has the **X** and **Y** attributes. It might also help to have a look at [Boto 3 Textract documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/1.9.244/reference/services/textract.html) and search for "Geometry".

This should work:

```py
for page in doc.pages:
    for field in page.form.fields:
        for array in field.geometry.polygon:
            polygon = []
            for point in array:
                x = point.X # or point["X"]
                y = point.Y # or point["X"]
                polygon.append((x, y))
            polygons.append(polygon)
```